# Correct way to set custom header component (TabComponent) in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

**Overview:**

I have to develop a `JTabbedPane`, which should have a default tab that is only shown if no other tab is shown (which I achieve using a `ContainerListener`).

Further, it should create a custom header for each added tab (which I achieve overriding `addTab`).

Following a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can be used as-is:

```
public class MyCustomTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

    private final JPanel defaultTab = new JPanel();

    public MyCustomTabbedPane() {
        super();

        JButton exampleButton = new JButton("Click me");
        exampleButton.addActionListener((e) -> addTab("New page", null, new JPanel()));
        defaultTab.add(exampleButton);

        addTab("Default", null, defaultTab);
        addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
                if (getTabCount() == 0) {
                    addTab("Default", null, defaultTab);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
                if (getTabCount() > 1) {
                    remove(defaultTab);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component) {
        int index = getTabCount();
        // Add new tab at the back with default header
        super.addTab(title, icon, component);
        // Create custom header based on default header
        Component header = createHeader(title, icon, getTabComponentAt(index));
        // Set custom header for added tab
        setTabComponentAt(index, header);
        // Select the added tab
        setSelectedIndex(index);
    }

    private Component createHeader(String title, Icon icon, Component header) {
        if(header == null) {
            header = new JLabel(title, icon, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Just an example header modification - "));
        panel.add(header);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem occurs at `super.addTab(title, icon, component);` within the `addTab` overriding, because it fires the `componentAdded` event at this point. Due to this event, the default page gets removed (and therefore, the number of tabs changes). And as a consequence to this, the value of `index` within `addTab` is not correct anymore and leads to `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`.

**Question:**

Can I tell the `JTabbedPane` to delay events between `super.addTab(title, icon, component)` and `setTabComponentAt(index, header)`? If this is not possible, is there another way how to add a new tab with custom header, without adding the tab with default header in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the need for `index` in `addTab()` by using the following code (see `setSelectedComponent()` replacing `setSelectedIndex()`, and `indexOfComponent(component)` replacing uses on `index`).
This way, I circumvent the access on an invalid index.

```
public class MyCustomTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

    private final JPanel defaultTab = new JPanel();

    public MyCustomTabbedPane() {
        super();

        JButton exampleButton = new JButton("Click me");
        exampleButton.addActionListener((e) -> addTab("New page", null, new JPanel()));
        defaultTab.add(exampleButton);

        addTab("Default", null, defaultTab);
        addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {

            @Override
            public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
                if (getTabCount() == 0) {
                    addTab("Default", null, defaultTab);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
                if (getTabCount() > 1) {
                    remove(defaultTab);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component) {
        // Add new tab at the back with default header
        super.addTab(title, icon, component);
        // Create custom header based on default header
        Component header = createHeader(title, icon, getTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(component)));
        // Set header for previously added tab
        setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(component), header);
        // Select the added tab
        setSelectedComponent(component);
    }

    private Component createHeader(String title, Icon icon, Component header) {
        if(header == null) {
            header = new JLabel(title, icon, SwingConstants.LEFT);
        }
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(new JLabel("Just an example header modification - "));
        panel.add(header);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the easiest would be to add after the `super.addTab()` line a line doing
`index = index == getTabCount() ? 0 : index` or
`index = index == getTabCount() ? index - 1 : index` or
`if (index == getTabCount()) { index-- }`

Comment: Thanks for you help. I was able to rebuild my solution without the need for the index, which seems more robust to me.